# Can I use Strapi on top of an existing (MongoDB) database?

Tags: strapi

I have an existing MongoDB database and add data via periodic serverless function calls from a third party API. Sometimes I still want to go in and fine tune some of the data via a CMS manually.

Would Strapi be appropriate if I also modify the sama database that Strapi uses directly and bypass its API?

I did a quick test and it looks like if I add a field directly in the DB that doesn't exist in the Strapi defined model, it doesn't get wiped out if I edit the document in Strapi.

Any other possible problems I might be missing, or is this a good use case for Strapi?

I do understand that I wouldn't be able to host Strapi as a serverless function.